# Next Button is working but the Previous Button wont work (Tabs)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, tabs

I'm a student and new to PHP. I'm currently working on a Skill Test project that displays one question on each tab and I included previous and next buttons that should be responsive/automatic. For example, if Im in tab 2, the previous button should lead to tab 1 and the next button to tab 3. If I go to tab 3, the prev btn should lead to tab 2 and the next btn to tab 4, and so on.. The next button is working perfectly fine but I dont have an idea why the previous button wont work. I hope someone can help me with this. Please. Thank you so much!

Here is my code:

```
        <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
        </script>

        <div class="tab">
          <button class="btn btn-default btnPrevious" data-direction="previous" type="button" onclick=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span></button>
          <button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button>
          <button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q2')">2</button>
          <button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q3')">3</button>
          <button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q4')">4</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btnNext" data-direction="next" type="button" onclick=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span></button>
        </div>            

      <form action="results.php" method="POST">
        <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
        <?php $index = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($result as $results):?>
                <div id="q<?php echo ($index++); ?>" class="tabcontent">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="form-group">   
                            <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $results['question']; ?> </h3>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="form-group">
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiona'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiona'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionb'];?>"><?php echo $results['optionb'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optionc'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" ame="ans[<?php echo $results['test_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $results['optiond'];?>"><?php echo $results['optiond'];?>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <center>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btnBack" data-direction="back" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q<?php echo ($index-=1); ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span>   Back</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btnNext" data-direction="next" type="button" onclick="openTab(event, 'q<?php echo ($index+=1); ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>  Next</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: create different button within each tab with there prev and next link

Comment: @newbie how exactly?

Comment: simple html what @gattbha described see snippet code html every tab has its own prev next button and links

Comment: @newbie please take a look at my code. The tabs are displayed by loop..thats why Im having a hard time coding for automatic previous and next buttons..

Answer (score 1):

Check this works for you

```js
$('.btn-right').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

  $('.btn-left').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
a.btn-left,a.btn-right{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  font-size:24px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tab_desc {
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Cases</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Experience</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="tab_desc">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right pagination">
                <a class="btn-right" id="btnNext"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="tab_desc">
                <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right pagination">
                <a class="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="tab_desc">
                <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right pagination">
                <a class="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="tab_desc">
                <h3>Menu 3</h3>
                <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right pagination">
                <a class="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I tried the codes above but the previous and next buttons are not clickable..

Comment: @Dza in snippet,it is working and I have updated also button check this

Comment: still not working on my device.. I cant click the buttons.. idk why :(

Comment: I dont know how to post codes in the comments.. anyway, the btn functions should be inside the <script></script>, right?

Comment: yes and you have to add class btn-right,btn-left for working it

Comment: in my code i have used <a class="btn-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a> this you can replace your button <button  class="btn btn-default btn-left"  type="button"></button> with it repectevely

Comment: hello you can put your code in jsfiddle , so I can check your issue

Comment: Hello sir, I edited my question. The codes you suggested above wont work on my device so I tried to find other ways to make my buttons work.. maybe you can help me with my new question..

Comment: I think you have to make Function different for Previous button like next and use i-- for FOR Loop in that function for tab click.....try it